# Findbugs gives "Null pointer dereference of System.out", why?

Tags: java, eclipse, findbugs, java-7

I am using Java 1.7, Eclipse 3.7 with the FindBugs plugin from the marketplace. The example is as nice as heaven:

```
class Application
{
  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    System.out.println( "Bla" );
  }
}
```

This message was not present in the past and the internal implementation was always in System:

```
public final static PrintStream out = null;
```

So Findbugs IS right, but did something change that the message occur now?

Comment: Not necessarily, there is likely a block somewhere that is assigning `out` to something (a `static` block).  Based on the documentation, FindBugs is still experimental and may not always work properly.  This sounds like a bug in findbugs...Ii assume the code works if you run it through a standard JVM?

Comment: Sure it works. I think it has something to do with the switch to Java 7 because the initialisation is NOT in the static {} anymore (which I think it was, I don't have a Java 6 version right now).

Answer (score 15):

Because in java 6 it looked like this:

```
public final static PrintStream out = nullPrintStream();

/**
 * The following two methods exist because in, out, and err must be
 * initialized to null.  The compiler, however, cannot be permitted to
 * inline access to them, since they are later set to more sensible values
 * by initializeSystemClass().
 */
private static PrintStream nullPrintStream() throws NullPointerException {
    if (currentTimeMillis() > 0) {
        return null;
    }
    throw new NullPointerException();
}
```

so I guess they simplified it in java 7 and added some exceptions to the compiler.

JVM manages out, in, and err in native code, so this error message it gives is pointless.

Answer (score 11):

This is marked as a [bug](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3139802&group_id=96405&atid=614693) in Findbugs 1.3.9. It has been fixed for Findbugs 2.0, and might be backported.

Comment: Unfortunately it's still happening. At least I still get this error by means of the Findbugs plugin of Maven. Which is supposed to use Findbugs 2 as of release 2.3.3.

Comment: In that case it might worth reporting the bug again, the comments clearly state it should be fixed in findbugs 2.

Answer (score 3):

This only happens with openjdk, not the sun jdk.

The problem is a patch posted in 2010 to allow system times older than 1970.

http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/distro-pkg-dev/2010-July/009869.html